# Is it possible to keep css style in a code/pre tag in markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, pre

I'm facing an issue while writing a markdown document.

I'd like to insert a diff code output from the console, containing colors, transformed to HTML via a script, something like this:

```
# Some title

The following code as been updated:

<pre>
<code>
<span style="color:green;">+</span><span style="color:green;">    if ($url !== $newUrl) {</span>
<span style="color:green;">+</span><span style="color:green;">        $newDomain = parse_url($newUrl, PHP_URL_HOST);</span>
</code>
</pre>

**Thank you**
```

I've added some Markdown just to show some context.

The problem is, using `pre`/`code`, the code structure is correct (correctly formated lines).
If I change it (switching to `code`/`pre`), or changing `code` or `pre` to `div`, I loose either the line breaks, or the coloration.

Here's the output of the above markdown: https://fiddle.md/tmvmwvztfd5d92xk65dwfx

Comment: Not sure why you would want `code`/`pre`. Valid HTML is `pre`/`code`. Any reason you can't use `pre`/`code`?

Comment: When using pre/code in that order, the structure is correct, with space, etc, but the html inside is removed, which is not what I want. I want to keep the html inside (for the style). Trying other alternatives didn't yield a better result. That's why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that Github have a `diff` expression who let you do something like this : https://gist.github.com/salmedina/ad8bea4f46de97ea132f71b0bca73663#file-markdowndiffexample-md

But I thinks that there is no such way to do what your want in Markdown.

Regards.

Comment: Neat! I just need to use a Markdown processor that have the diff syntax coloration in place :/

Comment: Any syntax highlighter (pygments, highlight.js, etc) should be able to handle `diff` as a "language" and output a colorized code block. Just insert the highlighter's HTML output into your Markdown document as-is. Of course, you may need to also ensure the rendered document points to the CSS rules that the highlighter expects to be defined.